# Откуда пошёл "свисток" как USB сетевой адаптер?

Tags: жаргон, компьютеры

Часто встречаю термин "свисток" — внешний сетевой адаптер, например, 3G или Wi-Fi.

Понятно, что нужен какой-то короткий термин для этого, но почему именно свисток? Он же не подаёт звуковых сигналов, и форма не похожа...

Comment: Как так не похожа?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Мне кажется, по форме как раз похож: небольшой удлинённый предмет с выступающей частью для вставления в отверстие (ротовое в случае настоящего свистка, USB-разъём в случае адаптера). А если развивать метафору, можно сказать, что как свисток при использовании издаёт звук, так и адаптер... Эээ, я не сильна в физике, но ведь что-то же он издаёт,подключаясь к сети?

Comment: И еще наверное по восприятию USB на слух - юююююэссссссби. Как свист. ;)

Comment: Да ладно вам притягивать за уши!))